# Issues while deserializing exception/throwable using Jackson in Java

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization

I am facing issues while deserializing `Exception` and `Throwable` instances using Jackson (version 2.2.1). Consider the following snippet:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
    objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
    objectMapper.enableDefaultTyping(DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, As.PROPERTY);

    try {
        Integer.parseInt("String");
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        RuntimeException runtimeException = new RuntimeException(e);
        String serializedException = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(runtimeException);
        System.out.println(serializedException);
        Throwable throwable = objectMapper.readValue(serializedException, Throwable.class);
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The output of `System.out.println` in the `catch` block is:

```
{
  "@class" : "java.lang.RuntimeException",
  "detailMessage" : "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: \"String\"",
  "cause" : {
    "@class" : "java.lang.NumberFormatException",
    "detailMessage" : "For input string: \"String\"",
    "cause" : null,
    "stackTrace" : [ {
      "declaringClass" : "java.lang.NumberFormatException",
      "methodName" : "forInputString",
      "fileName" : "NumberFormatException.java",
      "lineNumber" : 65
    }, {
      "declaringClass" : "java.lang.Integer",
      "methodName" : "parseInt",
      "fileName" : "Integer.java",
      "lineNumber" : 492
    }, {
      "declaringClass" : "java.lang.Integer",
      "methodName" : "parseInt",
      "fileName" : "Integer.java",
      "lineNumber" : 527
    }, {
      "declaringClass" : "test.jackson.JacksonTest",
      "methodName" : "main",
      "fileName" : "JacksonTest.java",
      "lineNumber" : 26
    } ],
    "suppressedExceptions" : [ "java.util.ArrayList", [ ] ]
  },
  "stackTrace" : [ {
    "declaringClass" : "test.jackson.JacksonTest",
    "methodName" : "main",
    "fileName" : "JacksonTest.java",
    "lineNumber" : 29
  } ],
  "suppressedExceptions" : [ "java.util.ArrayList", [ ] ]
}
```

which seems fine. But when I attempt to deserialize this using `objectMapper.readValue()`, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "declaringClass" (class java.lang.StackTraceElement), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@3c5ebd39; line: 9, column: 27] (through reference chain: java.lang.StackTraceElement["declaringClass"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:79)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:555)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:708)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JdkDeserializers$StackTraceElementDeserializer.deserialize(JdkDeserializers.java:414)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JdkDeserializers$StackTraceElementDeserializer.deserialize(JdkDeserializers.java:380)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:151)
...
```

I then tried using [mix-in annotations](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations), to ignore `declaringClass` in `java.lang.StackTraceElement`, but now the deserialized `Exception` doesn't contain the declaring class in its stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "String"
    at .main(JacksonTest.java:33)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "String"
    at .forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at .parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at .parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at .main(JacksonTest.java:30)
```

Am I missing anything? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There seems to be a Jackson JIRA entry for this [here](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-888). Jackson doesn't seem to be able to handle the `declaringClass` in `java.lang.StackTraceElement`, since the getter corresponding to this field is called `getClassName()`.

I fixed this issue by using a custom wrapper around `StackTraceElement` as suggested in the JIRA entry mentioned above. The custom wrapper (`CustomStackTraceElement`) will have the fields `declaringClass`, `methodName`, `fileName`, and `lineNumber` and the corresponding getters and setters in it. I modified the `catch` block (mentioned in the question) to be as follows:

```java
catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    RuntimeException runtimeException = new RuntimeException(e);
    e.printStackTrace();
    String serializedException = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(runtimeException);
    System.out.println(serializedException);

    String serializedStackTrace = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(transformStackTrace(runtimeException));
    String serializedStackTraceForCause = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(transformStackTrace(runtimeException.getCause()));

    Throwable throwable = objectMapper.readValue(serializedException, Throwable.class);
    List<CustomStackTraceElement> customStackTraceElementList = objectMapper.readValue(serializedStackTrace, List.class);
    List<CustomStackTraceElement> customStackTraceElementListForCause = objectMapper.readValue(serializedStackTraceForCause, List.class);

    throwable.setStackTrace(reverseTransformStackTrace(customStackTraceElementList));
    throwable.getCause().setStackTrace(reverseTransformStackTrace(customStackTraceElementListForCause));
    throwable.printStackTrace();
}
```

The `StackTraceElement[]` will be converted into `List<CustomStackTraceElement>` by the following method during serialization:

```java
private static List<CustomStackTraceElement> transformStackTrace(Throwable throwable)
{
    List<CustomStackTraceElement> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (StackTraceElement stackTraceElement : throwable.getStackTrace()) {
        CustomStackTraceElement customStackTraceElement =
            new CustomStackTraceElement(stackTraceElement.getClassName(),
                                        stackTraceElement.getMethodName(),
                                        stackTraceElement.getFileName(),
                                        stackTraceElement.getLineNumber());

        list.add(customStackTraceElement);
    }

    return list;
}
```

... and the reverse transformation will be done during deserialization:

```java
private static StackTraceElement[] reverseTransformStackTrace(List<CustomStackTraceElement> customStackTraceElementList)
{
    StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElementArray = new StackTraceElement[customStackTraceElementList.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < customStackTraceElementList.size(); i++) {
        CustomStackTraceElement customStackTraceElement = customStackTraceElementList.get(i);
        StackTraceElement stackTraceElement =
            new StackTraceElement(customStackTraceElement.getDeclaringClass(),
                                  customStackTraceElement.getMethodName(),
                                  customStackTraceElement.getFileName(),
                                  customStackTraceElement.getLineNumber());

        stackTraceElementArray[i] = stackTraceElement;
    }

    return stackTraceElementArray;
}
```

Now, after deserialization, the `Throwable` object has the expected stack trace in it.

Comment: Anyone knows if this was fixed properly in later versions of Jackson??

Comment: This is a good find. Thanks for the solution. Another solution is to add a mixin for StackTraceElement.

'''
public abstract class StackTraceElementMixin {

    @JsonProperty("className")
    private String declaringClass;
}
""

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the output you get in version 2.2.1 is not the same as I get with version 2.2.0 (which according to the website is the latest 2.x version). Besides the latest available 2.x version on the Maven Repository is 2.2.2. So I would try to either downgrade it to 2.2.0 or to upgrade it to 2.2.2. If any of the changes brings you the expected result, I would go further with that version and open a BUG in Jackson's JIRA.

And of course don't forget

```
objectMapper.configure( DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

from Michael's answer.

Comment: I use version 2.2.1 of Jackson. `SerializationConfig.Feature` corresponds to the old package structure (prior to version 2.0). I tried commenting out the two lines as you suggested (during serialization, deserialization, and the other combinations possible) but no luck. The deserialized `Throwable` doesn't contain the declaring class. And, I use Java 7 (this shouldn't matter a lot, though).

Comment: OK, I tested now also with version 2.2.0 and configured as Michael Cheremuhin said and I get also the class names in the stack trace (if that is all you miss). May I ask you where did you get version 2.2.1, as on the http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDownload website it is written that the last version is 2.2.0 ?

Comment: I got version 2.2.1 of Jackson from the Central Maven Repository (http://search.maven.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Add this:

```
objectMapper.configure( DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

And make out of the deserialized exception the same way, as for the first time:

```
System.out.println( objectMapper.writeValueAsString( throwable ) );
```

---

I used the following code:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
{
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure( SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true );
    objectMapper.configure( DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    objectMapper.setVisibility( PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY );
    objectMapper.enableDefaultTyping( ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY );

    try
    {
        Integer.parseInt( "String" );
    }
    catch( NumberFormatException e )
    {
        Throwable throwable = objectMapper.readValue( objectMapper.writeValueAsString( e ), Throwable.class );
        System.out.println( objectMapper.writeValueAsString( throwable ) );
    }
}
```

Added this jars: jackson-annotations-2.2.0.jar, jackson-core-2.2.0.jar and jackson-databind-2.2.0.jar.

After execution, the following is printed:

```
{
"@class" : "java.lang.NumberFormatException",
"detailMessage" : "For input string: \"String\"",
"cause" : null,
"stackTrace" : [ {
    "declaringClass" : "java.lang.NumberFormatException",
    "methodName" : "forInputString",
    "fileName" : "NumberFormatException.java",
    "lineNumber" : 48,
    "className" : "java.lang.NumberFormatException",
    "nativeMethod" : false
}, {
    "declaringClass" : "java.lang.Integer",
    "methodName" : "parseInt",
    "fileName" : "Integer.java",
    "lineNumber" : 449,
    "className" : "java.lang.Integer",
    "nativeMethod" : false
}, {
    "declaringClass" : "java.lang.Integer",
    "methodName" : "parseInt",
    "fileName" : "Integer.java",
    "lineNumber" : 499,
    "className" : "java.lang.Integer",
    "nativeMethod" : false
}, {
    "declaringClass" : "com.sample.bla.Main",
    "methodName" : "main",
    "fileName" : "Main.java",
    "lineNumber" : 24,
    "className" : "com.sample.bla.Main",
    "nativeMethod" : false
}, {
    "declaringClass" : "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl",
    "methodName" : "invoke0",
    "fileName" : "NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java",
    "lineNumber" : -2,
    "className" : "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl",
    "nativeMethod" : true
}, {
    "declaringClass" : "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl",
    "methodName" : "invoke",
    "fileName" : "NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java",
    "lineNumber" : 39,
    "className" : "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl",
    "nativeMethod" : false
}, {
    "declaringClass" : "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl",
    "methodName" : "invoke",
    "fileName" : "DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java",
    "lineNumber" : 25,
    "className" : "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl",
    "nativeMethod" : false
}, {
    "declaringClass" : "java.lang.reflect.Method",
    "methodName" : "invoke",
    "fileName" : "Method.java",
    "lineNumber" : 597,
    "className" : "java.lang.reflect.Method",
    "nativeMethod" : false
}, {
    "declaringClass" : "com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain",
    "methodName" : "main",
    "fileName" : "AppMain.java",
    "lineNumber" : 120,
    "className" : "com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain",
    "nativeMethod" : false
    } ],
    "message" : "For input string: \"String\"",
    "localizedMessage" : "For input string: \"String\""
}
```

Comment: I tried using this `DeserializationFeature`, but I get the same output as the one with mix-in annotations (i.e., there is no declaring class in the deserialized output). I need the complete `Exception`/`Throwable` information after it's deserialized -- it looks weird and incomplete otherwise.

Comment: I can`t understand, why are you trying to obtain the same result with throwable.printStackTrace() and objectMapper.writeValueAsString(runtimeException). Execute 'e.printStackTrace()' and you`ll get the same "weird and incomplete" out. Please, change the last line of your code to 'System.out.println( objectMapper.writeValueAsString( throwable ) );' and check the output.

Comment: The main issue I'm facing is with deserialization. If I say `objectMapper.writeValueAsString(runtimeException)`, I am not deserializing the `Throwable` at all -- it's just the serialized output. Consider a scenario where I need to serialize the `Throwable` on the server side, transmit the serialized output (in the form of a `String`) over the wire, and then deserialize it on the client side (using `objectMapper.readValue` method). The client should be able to view the complete `Throwable` information after it's deserialized.

Comment: You don't get me. I`m asking you to add 'objectMapper.writeValueAsString( throwable )', not 'objectMapper.writeValueAsString( runtimeException )'. Do you see the difference? You`re calling throwable.printStackTrace(), which won`t give you desired result. The deserialization process works fine. Your trying to get the result in a wrong way. So, REMOVE  'throwable.printStackTrace()' from your code and add 'objectMapper.writeValueAsString( throwable )' (NOT runtimeException).This will print you a full info for your DESERIALIZED object.

Comment: I tried using `objectMapper.writeValueAsString(throwable)` (after it's deserialized), but the output doesn't containing the declaring class; it's empty (which is similar to printing the stack trace). To be clear, I want the `Throwable` object to print the same stack trace before serialization and after deserialization. I'm saying the deserialization process doesn't work fine, since the stack trace isn't preserved in its entirety.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34971/discussion-between-jackall-and-michael-cheremuhin)

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue. I'm using this code now, and it allows me to serialize and deserialize exceptions with proper types (i.e. a `RuntimeException` will be a `RuntimeException` again :)):

```
public static ObjectMapper createObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(null, null, new DefaultDeserializationContext.Impl(
            new BeanDeserializerFactory(new DeserializerFactoryConfig()) {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public JsonDeserializer<Object> buildThrowableDeserializer(
                        DeserializationContext ctxt, JavaType type, BeanDescription beanDesc)
                        throws JsonMappingException {
                    return super.buildBeanDeserializer(ctxt, type, beanDesc);
                }

            }));

    mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, Visibility.NONE);
    mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);

    mapper.addMixIn(Throwable.class, ThrowableMixin.class);
    mapper.addMixIn(StackTraceElement.class, StackTraceElementMixin.class);

    return mapper;
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@class")
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY)
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "message", "localizedMessage", "suppressed" })
abstract class ThrowableMixin {

    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "$id")
    private Throwable cause;
}

abstract class StackTraceElementMixin {

    @JsonProperty("className")
    private String declaringClass;

}
```

I'm manipulating the `BeanDeserializerFactory` to make `buildThrowableDeserializer` not treat `Throwable` any special but just like any other `Object`. Then using `Mixins` to define the "special" handling of `Throwable` and `StackTraceElement` to my liking.

Comment: Note that the other mapper configurations are what we actually need for our application, not what is required by this example

Answer (score 1):

Try using polymorphism so that jackson deserializer knows what kind of Throwable to create:

```
/**
 * Jackson module to serialize / deserialize Throwable
 */
public class ThrowableModule extends SimpleModule {
  public ThrowableModule() {
    super("Throwable", new Version(1, 0, 0, null, null, null));
  }

  @Override
  public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {
    context.setMixInAnnotations(Throwable.class, ThrowableAnnotations.class);
  }

  /**
   * Add annotation to Throwable so that the class name is serialized with the instance data.
   */
  @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "class")
  static abstract class ThrowableAnnotations {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it so necessary to use json serialization? Looks liks there are some bugs with throwables. Why not use system api:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(  );
ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream( byteArrayOutputStream );
objectOutputStream.writeObject( e );

ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream( byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray() );
ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream( byteArrayInputStream );
Throwable t = (Throwable) objectInputStream.readObject();
```