# Serializing java.lang.Error

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, resteasy

I am serializing the following class so I can send over a REST interface:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Object that holds information on result of executed method on remote     agent.
*/

public class ResultMessage implements Message {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -8740453631197286688L;
private Exception exception;
private Error error;
private String exceptionType;
private String errorType;

public String getCmdResponse() {
    return cmdResponse;
}

public Exception getException() {
    return exception;
}

public void setException(Exception e) {
    this.exception = e;
    if (e != null) {
        this.exceptionType = e.getClass().getName();
    }
}

public String getExceptionType() {
    return exceptionType;
}

public Error getError() {
    return error;
}

public void setError(Error error) {
    this.error = error;
    if (error != null) {
        this.errorType = error.getClass().getName();
    }
}

public String getErrorType() {
    return errorType;
}    

}
```

I can encode Exceptions without any problems but I can't seem to encode Errors. The following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/cfg/ObjectRepositoryFactory
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.cfg.ObjectRepositoryFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 7 more
```

When I try to serialize this I get:

```
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ReaderException:      
org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized 
field "exception" (Class java.lang.Throwable), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: org.jboss.netty.buffer.ChannelBufferInputStream@6cc1e35f;   
line: 1, column: 2080] (through reference chain:  
com.rest.message.ResultMessage["error"]->java.lang.Throwable["exception"])
```

This is where the fields get set:

```
try {
        verb.runCommand(result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.fatal("Failed to execute command [" + msg.getCommand() + "] due to exception");
        System.err.println("Exception: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
        LOGGER.trace(e.getMessage(), e);
        result.setException(e);
    } catch (Error ee) {
        result.setError(ee);
        System.err.println("Error: ");
        ee.printStackTrace();
        LOGGER.trace(ee.getMessage(), ee);
        LOGGER.fatal("Failed to execute command [" + msg.getCommand() + "] due to error");
    } finally {
        sendResult(result);
    }
```

When I catch a java.lang.Exception it works fine, but not this particular java.lang.Error.

Comment: Do you really need to keep track of and serialize complete Throwables with their stacktrace and all? Could you not just log the error when it happens and keep track of an error code or -message instead?

Answer (score 0):

UnrecognizedPropertyException - Specialized JsonMappingException sub-class specifically used to indicate problems due to encountering a JSON property that could not be mapped to an Object property (via getter, constructor argument or field). (Source: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/UnrecognizedPropertyException.html)

Can you show all of the setter and getters?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the setters/getters for the Error - I have added those in.

Comment: I belive this is exactly the same issue as mentioned http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855538/issues-while-deserializing-exception-throwable-using-jackson-in-java. Jackson has problem with Throwable and how to solve it is also written there.